# get_the_term_list without specific category

Tags: custom-taxonomy, customization, terms

I am using :

```
$term_link = get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'portfolio_category', '', '<br />', '');
```

to get the category and link to it.

There is any way to get all category despite specific one?

Now i get :

```
<a href="http://5.10.105.54/~shayjcoi/shayj/portfolio_category/Yellow/" rel="tag">Yellow</a></br><a href="http://5.10.105.54/~shayjcoi/shayj/portfolio_category/Main/" rel="tag">Main</a>
```

And i want to get all the category despite the "Main" category.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you want is to exclude a term. It is odd that such is not an option with that function but you can use a filter on `get_the_terms`:

```
function exclude_my_term($terms, $post, $taxonomy) {
  remove_filter('get_the_terms','exclude_my_term',10,3);
  unset($terms[123]); // where 123 is the ID of the term to exclude
  return $terms;
}
add_filter('get_the_terms','exclude_my_term',10,3);
```

You probably want to run that just before your call to `get_the_term_list()`.